# Troubleshooting Skyper 32Pro R + Adapter Board 1 Skyper 32Pro R

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver, semiconductors, gate-driving, igbt

Hello I am trying to test an IGBT [SKM145GB066D](https://www.semikron.com/products/product-classes/igbt-modules/detail/skm145gb066d-22890045.html) with the [Adapter Board 1 Skyper 32Pro R](https://www.semikron.com/products/product-classes/igbt-driver/detail/board-1-skyper-32pro-r-l6100231.html) and gate driver [Skyper 32 Pro R](https://www.semikron.com/products/product-classes/igbt-driver/detail/skyper-32-pro-r-l6100202.html), but cannot make it work. I've spend 2 weeks trying, but it seems like some protection in the board is being activated and impeding the IGBT to switch on, when my switching signal (+15V) is on.

I followed the [gate driver datasheet](https://www.semikron.com/products/product-classes/igbt-driver/detail/skyper-32-pro-r-l6100202.html), and I am using the following parameters:

- Rgon: 4.7 ohms (tried 1.8ohms also)
- Rgoff: 4.7 ohms (tried 1.8ohms also)
- Roff_sc: 47 ohms (tried shorting it also)
- Rce: 18 kohms
- Cce: 330 pF
- Rvce: 0 ohms (shorted)
- Shorted R172 for temperature monitoring circuit, as suggested by datasheet

And nothing can make it work. This is the schematic I am using:
[image]

My switching signal is 0/+15V at 5kHz, and this is what I am getting for Vce (green) and Vge (yellow):

[image]

The gate signal is between -7V and 15V as expected (and stated in the datasheet), but it only lasts for around 7 microseconds and then the board is disabled.

When I monitored the error signal (pin 9 of connector X200 in the adapter board), I noticed the board gets disabled every time I set my top IGBT switching signal to high (+15V). This picture shows the error signal in yellow, and Vge in green (according to the datasheet, when there's no error, the error signal stays at 15V, and when the board detects any problem it shifts the error signal to 0V):

[image]

Things I tried already:

a) Disabling the Dynamic Short Circuit Protection (DCSP) of the TOP side, by connecting SEC_TOP_VCE_IN to SEC_TOP_GND, and also disabling it for the BOT side.
b) Disabling Soft Turn-off (STO)
c) Run the tests with or without the IGBTs connected to a load (DC link voltages tested: 20 and 30VDC; loads tested 10kohms and 100 ohms)
d) Changing the power supply for the gate driver
e) Using a different power supply for the adapter board and to provide my switching signals

Could anybody think of anything that I am missing. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you ask at Semikron service ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they couldn't help yet

Comment: can you solve the problem? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem while trying to get a Skyper 42R to work running on its adaptor board.

In my case, after putting a 0 Ω resistor instead of the 1 kΩ (intended for 1700 V modules) it came with at the VCE input for DSCP monitoring, the voltage threshold for the steady state of VCE reference automatically increased to a voltage compatible with the VCE saturation voltage of the module SKM400GB1250D I had at hand.

After that it worked like a charm. Don't forget to double check correct wiring for the open collector as well as for TOP&BOT VCE inputs. An isolated power supply is a most.

Comment: Good job. It was definitely a technical service issue ...